# Substitute ConnectionString for some users on asp.net Web Site

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, connection-string, appsettings

I modify asp.net Web Site. I need use different connection strings for users. Web Site use Entity Framework for data access.

How can I substitute settings in runtime? 
I can instantiate with specified ConnectionString, but it will require multiple changes, because used default constructor everywhere.

I find solution for projects - using partial class for Settings. But Settings no in Web Site (I mistake maybe?).

Comment: why would you use different connection strings for different users?

Comment: you may require an admin account for one user with permissions to certain tables that another user doesnt have. Or maybe you split apart databases by company, etc etc etc

Comment: We want use general database for auth and different instances for our branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply load a new connect string from either your web.config, database, or whereever you use it and assign it to your context object when you create it. See:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2efc32f7-23ad-4fad-84cf-279badb394a5

Comment: No, it's not my option. In legacy code many constructors with no parameters. I must set connect for one user to db1 and for second user to another db. It should be transparent for legacy code. In EF (app.settings) project use ConnectionString named "Entities" and in web.config use same ConnectionString. I want in web site after authentication change it property.

Comment: you _have to_ refactor your code to support this. There is no magic bullet. If you modify these settings at runtime in the config, your application is affected. The other option is to alter your entity framework constructor - which is a refactor. You could refactor them all to have a class that provides this value but its still a refactor of all your locations that instantiate the context to use this new class to do this.